# Use text variable in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to use a text variable for a html, pdf, and word output with knitr.
This is the code I currently have in markdown

I want to set a variable

> var <- "just some text"

so that I don't need to write the text 3 different times

(please apologize the bad code, I am very new to this)

> ````
> For HTML Only
> ```{asis, echo=is_html_output()}
>   <p>just some text</p>
> ```
> For PDF Only
> \color{ecbblue}{\scriptsize{just some text}}
>
> For DOCX Only
> ```{asis, echo=is_word_output()}
> just some text
> ````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your variable in an invisible code chunk and output it in an inline expression. That way you don't need to handle `<p>` etc.:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
var <- "just some text"
h2 <- "Text2"
```

## `r h2`

`r if(knitr::is_latex_output()) paste("\\textcolor{blue}{\\scriptsize", var, "}") else var`
````

Note that I am using `\textcolor` instead of `\color`, since the latter does not take an argument and will make all following text also blue.

Comment: currently I have the html structered as follows:

<h2>Text1>
<p></p>
<h3>Text2</h3>
<span>Text3</span>
```
Is it possible to keep this structure with your approach ?

Comment: @HansGeber MAybe we have an XY-problem here. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to generate a report. All the calculation and graphs are done in r.
Now I want a similar output in PDF, Word and html.
Since some parts of the report are dynamic and used by  PDF, Word and html I need some variables.

Comment: @HansGeber You can combine inline code with markdown markup. See the updated answer. There should be no need to write explicit HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work in **LaTex** you can use this code :

```
\usepackage{xspace}
newcommand{\VarName}{text to insert\xspace}
```

Then whenever you want

> text to insert

So as an example you could do :

```
\color{blue}{\scriptsize{\VarName}}
```

would return *text to insert* in blue just like you want. This will indeed only work for text variable.

---

Edit : while the other answer is good, if you want to do it the R way I suggest to instead use the `pander` package which does a really good job and is even simpler.

```
install.packages("pander")
library("pander")
```

For **LaTeX(PDF)** in your R chunks simply do :

```
pander(cat("\\textcolor{red}{", var ,"}"))
```

For **HTML** in your R chunks simply do :

```
pander(cat("<span style=color:red>", var, "</span>"))
```

Comment: Hey Gainz, thank you very much for your answer, does this work for html as well, when I have severall tags?

Comment: Hi @HansGeber for html you could use : ``pander(cat("<span style=color:red>", var, "</span>"))``